# How to prioritize goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I want to call two endpoints at the same time (A and B). But if I got a response 200 from both I need to use the response from A otherwise use B response.
If B returns first I need to wait for A, in other words, I must use A whenever A returns 200.

Can you guys help me with the pattern?

Thank you

Comment: What happens in B returns before A?

Comment: Need to wait for A

Answer (score 4):

Wait for a result from A.  If the result is not good, then wait from a result from B.  Use a buffered channel for the B result so that the sender does not block when A is good.

In the following snippet, `fnA()` and `fnB()` functions that issue requests to the endpoints, consume the response and cleanup. I assume that the result is a `[]byte`, but it could be the result of decoding JSON or something else.  Here's an example for `fnA`:

```
func fnA() ([]byte, error) {
    r, err := http.Get("http://example.com/a")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer r.Body.Close() // <-- Important: close the response body!
    if r.StatusCode != 200 {
        return nil, errors.New("bad response")
    }
    return ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
}
```

Define a type to hold the result and error.

```
 type response struct {
     result []byte
     err error 
 }
```

With those preliminaries done, here's how to prioritize A over B.

```
a := make(chan response)
go func() {
    result, err := fnA()
    a <- response{result, err}
}()

b := make(chan response, 1) // Size > 0 is important!
go func() {
    result, err := fnB()
    b <- response{result, err}
}()

resp := <-a
if resp.err != nil {
    resp = <-b
    if resp.err != nil {
        // handle error.  A and B both failed.
    }
}
result := resp.result
```

If the application does not execute code concurrently with A and B, then there's no need to use a goroutine for A:

```
b := make(chan response, 1) // Size > 0 is important!
go func() {
    result, err := fnB()
    b <- response{result, err}
}()

result, err := fnA()
if err != nil {
    resp = <-b
    if resp.err != nil {
        // handle error.  A and B both failed.
    }
    result = resp.result
}
```

Comment: This doesn't close the response body for B in all cases, leaking network connections. fnA and fnB should yield byte slices or  concrete types representing the decoded responses instead. If the response bodies are large you can also, in case A is good, start a new goroutine that waits for B and copies its response body to io.Discard and then closes the response body.

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting you to use something like this, this is a bulky solution, but there you can start more than two endpoints for you needs.

```
func endpointPriorityTest() {

const (
    sourceA = "a"
    sourceB = "b"
    sourceC = "c"
)

type endpointResponse struct {
    source   string
    response *http.Response
    error
}

epResponseChan := make(chan *endpointResponse)

endpointsMap := map[string]string{
    sourceA: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
    sourceB: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/10",
    sourceC: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/100",
}

for source, endpointURL := range endpointsMap {
    source := source
    endpointURL := endpointURL
    go func(respChan chan<- *endpointResponse) {
        // You can add a delay so that the response from A takes longer than from B
        // and look to the result map
        // if source == sourceA {
        //  time.Sleep(time.Second)
        // }
        resp, err := http.Get(endpointURL)

        respChan <- &endpointResponse{
            source:   source,
            response: resp,
            error:    err,
        }
    }(epResponseChan)
}

respCache := make(map[string]*http.Response)

// Reading endpointURL responses from chan
for epResp := range epResponseChan {
    // Skips failed requests
    if epResp.error != nil {
        continue
    }

    // Save successful response to cache map
    respCache[epResp.source] = epResp.response

    // Interrupt reading channel if we've got an response from source A
    if epResp.source == sourceA {
        break
    }
}

fmt.Println("result map: ", respCache)

// Now we can use data from cache map
// resp, ok :=respCache[sourceA]
// if ok{
//  ...
// }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally in golang, channel are used for communicating between goroutines.
You can orchestrate your scenario with following sample code.
basically you pass channel into your `callB` which will hold response. You don't need to run `callA` in goroutine as you always need result from that endpoint/service

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    resB := make(chan int)
    go callB(resB)
    res := callA()
    if res == 200 {
        fmt.Print("No Need for B")
    } else {
        res = <-resB
        fmt.Printf("Response from B : %d", res)
    }
}

func callA() int {
    time.Sleep(1000)
    return 200
}

func callB(res chan int) {
    time.Sleep(500)
    res <- 200
}
```

**Update**: As suggestion given in comment, above code leaks "callB"

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    resB := make(chan int, 1)
    go callB(resB)
    res := callA()
    if res == 200 {
        fmt.Print("No Need for B")
    } else {
        res = <-resB
        fmt.Printf("Response from B : %d", res)
    }
}

func callA() int {
    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
    return 200
}

func callB(res chan int) {
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    res <- 200
}
```

Comment: This leaks the goroutine for B

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thanks for pointing it out, made changes

Comment: You're now leaking the "cancel" context if the `B` results is used. Always ensure `cancel` is called regardless.

Answer (score 0):

[@Zombo 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70933640/1218512) has the correct logic flow. Piggybacking off this, I would suggest one addition: leveraging the [context](https://pkg.go.dev/context) package.

Basically, any potentially blocking tasks should use `context.Context` to allow the call-chain to perform more efficient clean-up in the event of early cancelation.

`context.Context` also can be leveraged, in your case, to abort the `B` call early if the `A` call succeeds:

```
func failoverResult(ctx context.Context) *http.Response {

    // wrap the (parent) context
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
 
    // if we return early i.e. if `fnA()` completes first
    // this will "cancel" `fnB()`'s request.
    defer cancel()

    b := make(chan *http.Response, 1)
    go func() {
        b <- fnB(ctx)
    }()

    resp := fnA(ctx)
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        resp = <-b
    }

    return resp
}
```

`fnA` (and `fnB`) would look something like this:

```
func fnA(ctx context.Context) (resp *http.Response) {
    req, _ := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET", aUrl)
    
    resp, _ = http.DefaultClient.Do(req)  // TODO: check errors
    return
}
```